# How to add ASP.NET MVC 5 to Web API 2 project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have begun with Empty web solution including folders and core references of Web API. The solution has developed to expose some important functionalities and data to mobile applications. Now I need to improve the application into ASP.NET MVC 5 application.  What are additional features and configurations I have to perform after adding MVC 5, JQuery and Bootstrap references(From NuGet)? Is there any easy methods that I can follow to update them at once?

(Please consider that I have added so much features in my Web API solution. So starting with new solution is not an option to me now.)

Comment: Adding MVC as [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/) package will work

Comment: But adding MVC not creates any *config.cs files. If I add routeconfig manually dose it work as same as started developing with the mvc template and not making any severe issues in future?

Comment: Your web.config will be fine. Adding MVC via nuget is the most hassle free way of doing it. I add mvc to webapi projects and vice versa all the time, you'll be fine.